# Issues with code blocks in new design

Tags: bug, design

Have noticed two quirks with code blocks in the new design. First off, `inline code` seems to use a different font to distinct blocks:

```
like this one
```

Secondly, code blocks are not compatible with lists.

- Using inline style blocks renders like so:

`this is code block using the backticks
that goes over two lines`

- But using a regular block...

  indented with four spaces
  renders like this.
  This should be 3 lines!
- Yes, that line above is indented in the markdown!

Comment: I've noticed similar behavior with the 4 spaces not working correctly as well. I've needed to use the in-line code style button to fix formatting problems with code when all I normally would have needed to do was space over a single line of code to fix what was broken.

Comment: Also the backtick option results in the white gap between lines as in the example so it's not ideal!